# CoreOS: config network interface on simple machine call missing resources

Tags: vagrant, coreos

I'm following [official documentation](https://coreos.com/docs/running-coreos/platforms/vagrant/#single-machine) of CoreOS configuration with Vagrant step by step, and when I execute command `vagrant up` It's present some problem on phase: **Configuring and enabling network interfaces...**.

**The output:**

```
devops@devops-server:~/workspace/coreos-vagrant$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'core-01' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> core-01: Importing base box 'coreos-alpha'...
==> core-01: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> core-01: Setting the name of the VM: coreos-vagrant_core-01_1406017161344_20671
==> core-01: Fixed port collision for 22 => 2222. Now on port 2200.
==> core-01: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> core-01: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    core-01: Adapter 1: nat
    core-01: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> core-01: Forwarding ports...
    core-01: 22 => 2200 (adapter 1)
==> core-01: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> core-01: Booting VM...
==> core-01: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    core-01: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2200
    core-01: SSH username: core
    core-01: SSH auth method: private key
    core-01: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    core-01: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
==> core-01: Machine booted and ready!
==> core-01: Setting hostname...
==> core-01: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

mv /tmp/etcd-cluster.service /media/state/units/

Stdout from the command:



Stderr from the command:

mv: cannot move '/tmp/etcd-cluster.service' to '/media/state/units/': No such file or directory
```

**I don't know what's the problem?**

I'm authenticated on coreos vm and this machine not have resource: `/media/state/units/`. **Why? it's normal?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem it's I have old version of CoreOS, currently Beta version 367.1.0 not present these problem...then I update and all work successful!.

Thanks to @RobSzumski from [CoreOS-dev](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/coreos-dev) groups to showme the light.